# Localhost login after installation

Tags: installation, software-center

I recently installed Ubuntu 12.04 on my computer with a USB stick cause I don't have a CD drive. The normal ISO didn't work, so I used the text installer and completed all the steps somehow. Eventually it showed "Finishing Installation" and rebooted and I was met with a prompt saying "Localhost login tty1" or something.

I searched some old forums and tried out the login and password as root, guest, ubuntu etc but all in vain. I used the rescue mode and tried to install `ubuntu-desktop` with:

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop
```

it says it is not installed and attempts to install. So I think I found
the problem. The desktop is not istalled. But when I run this command it
says it wants some disk space. I press enter and then it asks to insert
the ubuntu CD in `/media/cdrom/` and press Enter again. But as I told, I don't have a CD drive, so can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 0):

Can you drop to a root prompt from rescue mode?

Then you can manually mount your usb device to `/media/cdrom/` by first creating that directory with `mkdir /media/cdrom/` then `mount /dev/sdx /media/cdrom` where `sdx` should be replaced with the drive letter for USB device(unmount USB device if automatically mounted). Then you should be able to install. After that unmount the usb `umount /media/cdrom` and delete `rm /media/cdrom`.

Comment: thanks for replying but when I try to mount it says this :

Comment: @Yash Is something missing here?

Comment: it says that /dev/sdb1 is already mounted or /media/cdrom is busy.

Comment: @Yash As I've mentioned earlier unmount USB device with `umount` if it is automatically mounted on insertion, just run `mount` and it'll show you the mounted devices(that way you'll also know if `/media/cdrom/` is really occupied). After unmounting don't remove the USB, keeping it inserted issue the `mount` command to remount the USB device at `/media/cdrom`

Comment: So when I run just mount it displays a list in which there is no mention of the usb stick or /media/cdrom and still it says that /dev/sdb1 is already mounted or /media/cdrom is busy.

Comment: @Yash the usb device should show up as /dev/sdb1 in the output of `mount` if you have no partitions in it and if you have one hard disk.

Comment: that's waht i said, it does'nt show up in the mounted list

Comment: @Yash That's strange. Try unmounting it with device name like `umount /dev/sdb1` and inform what it says.

Comment: I ran unmount /dev/sdb1 and it says not found.
and btw can you come on chat?

Comment: it's not `unmount`, it's `umount` ;)

Comment: hey wait. so now i successfully mounted the device on /media/cdrom and checked with mount. and then I again tried to install desktop but still the same.

Comment: So you are not getting any output even after selecting `/media/cdrom`,is that it? If there any error messages please mention it.

Comment: I'm sorry for wasting your time but now I'm really frustrated with this computer and I'm currently re installing windows 7 on it.